# Is there any libc project that does not requires linux kernel

Tags: c, libc

I am using a custom user space environment that has barely no OS support: only one char device, mass storage interface and a single network socket.

To provide C programming to this platform, I need a libc. Is there any libc project that is configurable enough so that I can map low-level IO to the small API I have access to ?

AFAIK glibc and uclibc are expecting linux syscalls, so I can't use them (without trying to emulate linux syscalls, which is something I prefer to avoid).

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921553/small-libc-for-embedded-systems

Comment: How come I did miss that one ! thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different libc's to choose from, but all will need some work to integrate into your system.

- uClibc has a [list](http://www.uclibc.org/other_libs.html) of other C libraries.
  The most interesting ones on that list are probably

  - [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/)
  - [newlib](http://sources.redhat.com/newlib/)
- [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) has a [LIBC](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/devel/libs/clib/)
- [EGLIBC](http://www.eglibc.org/) might be simpler to port than the "standard" glibc.

Comment: Thanks. Doing the integration work is not an issue. I simply want to avoid rewriting another printf, fread, etc... whereas some cool project already did it for me.
Any insights about differences between newlib and libc (features, stability) ?

Answer (score 1):

[newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) might serve this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Newlib, looks a good candidate. Hopefully, someone here may know some other project I can compare to.